# Use systemparameter in report/xml in Odoo

Tags: xml, odoo

I would like to use a boolean value from the SystemParameters in an xml t-if statement.
The model is ir.config_parameter which i can use in .py but I need the id for the systemparameter.

```
<t t-if="#what here??#.base_setup.show_effect">
   ...
</t>
```

Does anyone know what to write?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you have a recordset in the context of that qweb report, like `o` or `doc`, just use that and its `env` (Odoo environment with model registry) to use other models functionality.

```xml
<t t-if="o.env['ir.config_parameter'].get_param('key_of_your_config_parameter') == 'True'">
```

Keep in mind that values of model `ir.config_parameter` are texts. You can either parse them or just compare to texts, like in my example code above.

Comment: Yes I can use o.env but it says syntrax error

<t t-if="o.env['ir.config_parameter].get_param('product_manufacturer.installed') == 'True'">

Comment: There was a missing `'` in my answer (after `_parameter`), i've corrected it.